# How to access MySQL database that is on another machine, located in a different locations (NOT LOCAL) with python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python, remote-server

I am finished with my project and now I want to put it on my website where people could download it and use it. My project is connected to my MySQL and it works on my machine. On my machine, I can read, and modify my database with python. It obviously, will not work if a person from another country tries to access it. How can I make it so a person from another town, city, or country could access my database and be able to read it?

I tried using SSH but I feel like it only works on a local network.

I have not written a single line of code on this matter because I have no clue how to get started.

I probably know how to read my database on a local network but I have no clue how to access it from anywhere else.

Any help, tips, or solutions would be great and appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You should not let other access your local database within your home network. Create a web application and push the data to the mysql server of your chosen web hosting provider and user your web application to interact with it.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to run a MySQL server from your home PC and allow others to connect and access data? Well, you would need to make sure the correct port is forwarded in your router and firewall, default is TCP 3306. Then simply provide the user with your current IP address (could change).

1. Determine the correct MySQL Server port being listened on.
2. Allow port forwarding on the TCP protocol and the port you determined, default is 3306.
3. Allow incoming connections on this port from software firewall if any.
4. Provide the user with your current IP Address, Port, and Database name.
5. If you set login credentials, make sure the user has this as well.
6. That's it. The user should be able to connect with the IP Address, Port, Database Name, Username, and Password.